# Scrollview no horizontal scrollbar

Tags: wpf, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I have been several hours fighting with this. It is killing me alreayd and I feel shame for myself :(

I can not make the horizontal scrollbar to appear here. Can anybody point me why?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Canvas Width="2000" Height="2000" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Test text</TextBlock>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Canvas.Left="430" Canvas.Top="30">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Another test text</TextBlock>
            </Grid>

        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The vertical scrollbar works perfect.

Thnk you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I already find my self an answer. It was positng it and find the correct aproach in google :(

I was not using the scrollview correctly

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Panel_SFP_SerialIDInfo" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Canvas Width="2000" Height="2000">
```

Now it works as expected. 
Hope it helps somebody :)